# R data.table: How to use apply function?

Tags: r, data.table, apply

I need to briefly explain the context before letting you know my question.

I am trying to process a large graph, namely the Social circles: Google+ [here](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/ego-Gplus.html). The file *gplus_combined.txt* downloaded from that site is read by using data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
data = fread('gplus_combined.txt',stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Variable data is of dimensions dim(data) = c(30494865,2) and here is an example of a row of data:

```
>data[1,]
>1: 112188647432305746617 107727150903234299458
```

The two long integer strings are ids of nodes of the graph, and each row of data corresponds to an edge between the first and second node ids. Since working with node ids like those are not very convenient, I'd like to convert them to numbers using R function *strtoi*. Here is what I have tried

```
  M = matrix(0,2,2)
  for (i in 1:2) {
    for (j in 1:2) {
      M[i,j] = strtoi(data[i,j,with = FALSE])
    }
  }
  print(M)

      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] 47826 45374
[2,] 65616  2462
```

This works well, for just two rows of data. But it is too slow for processing about 30 millions rows of data. So I want to use R function *apply* to speed up the calculation. The problem is that if I just use

```
apply(data[1:2,], 1:2, strtoi)

[1,] NA NA
[2,] NA NA
```

then it returns a 2x2 matrix with NA entries. Note that to get the matrix M above, I need to include the parameter with = FALSE,

```
strtoi(data[i,j,with = FALSE])
```

otherwise M would also be a matrix of NA entries. Is there a way to pass the option with = FALSE to apply function? Or any other faster way to get the same result like matrix M? Any sugguestions/comments are greatly appreciated!

Thank you for spending your time reading this long post!

Comment: there might be integer overflow when you convert that long string into an integer.

Comment: @chinsoon12: Thank you, I didn't even think about that possibility. In fact, those integer strings are so long that if I run for loop, I estimate it would take me at least 6 hours to finish the conversion. I don't really know how to handle those string besides converting them to integers.

Comment: can you keep them as strings?

Comment: You did `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`, so I guess your data _already is integer_. Try `data[ , (1:2) := lapply(.SD, as.integer)]`. The value `112188647432305746617` will be converted to a much smaller integer. If this value is important to you, try storing `unique(data)` to keep as a lookup table.

Comment: @MichaelChirico: Thank you so much! Your suggestion is exactly what I need. I still have to check the integer overflow warned by chinsoon12 though.

Comment: @legon we can be confident that won't happen because there are at most 30M (# of rows) unique values in each column, which won't overflow. if it's node IDs on a graph as you said, likely the number of unique values is much smaller.

Comment: (1) I wouldn't think you need to `strtoi` each value, `data[, (1:2) := lapply(.SD, strtoi)]` or `data[, (1:2) := lapply(.SD, .as.numeric)]` might suffice. Note `as.numeric`, since your numbers are all too big for R's 32-bit integers. (2) I don't think the confidence of no-overflow is warranted: not having looked at the data, is it a foregone conclusion that the vertex numbering starts at 1 and is numbered contiguously?

Comment: @r2evans: Thank you for your suggestion! I ended up using those integer strings as keys instead of converting them.